# Azure Logic App Outlook Connector "Send Email with Options"

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am facing an issue with “Send Email with Options” Azure Logic App Outlook connector. Below is a screenshot of my logic app.

Logic App is for the below scenario:

1. Using Dynamics 365 connector, I get Accounts records based on some filter criteria and get the corresponding Contacts for these Accounts. Let’s say, I got 2 Accounts. Each of these Accounts will have 2 Contacts each.

Account 1: [user1email, user2email]

Account 2: [user3email, user4email]

2. Separate emails(I am using “Send Email with Options” Outlook connector) should be sent to all the above 4 Contacts at once. To achieve this, I am using 2 “For Each” connector, with outside “For Each” to iterate through Accounts, and inside “For Each” for Contacts.
3. For each user, once the email is sent, I need to update the Dynamics 365 Contact record for this user saying “Email Sent to User”.
4. Based on the option selected by the user in the email,  I will be updating the Dynamics 365 Contact record for the same user as “User Accepted” if he clicked Approve or “User Rejected” if he clicked Reject in the email that was sent.

When the outlook connector “Send Email” is used, it works fine and sends emails to each of the user at once.
However, with “Send Email with Options”, it does not let me send email to all 4 users at once. It first sends an email to user1email and user3email.
Now, until user1 and user3 click on the option in the email that was sent to them, the emails to user2 and user4 are not sent as the logic app is waiting for the email response of user1 and user3.

Is there any alternate method or suggestion to use “Send email with options” for sending emails to all 4 users at once?
Is there a way to continue with the logic app while waiting for the email response to come back?

#### Logic App Screenshot

[image: Logic App Screenshot]

Comment: Please use Markdown to show the screenshot inline: `![][url]`, not `[][url]`.

Comment: @aduguid - Thanks for sharing the tip. When I was trying to use markdown in another post today, it gave the error - "You need at least 10 reputation to post images." So, I need to wait before I can use markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to **...** next to **For Each and** choose **Settings**. Then go to **Concurrency Control** and switch to On